# Matrices properties discussion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been thinking about the most interesting property of the matrices that I have learnt and I finally concluded that the one that is the most interesting one is the Cauchy Theorem of determinant which states that for $A, B\in\mathbb{C}^{n, n} $
$$
\det (AB) =\det(A) \cdot \det(B) 
$$
My question is what is Your favourite and the most beautiful theorem (or maybe some trick) for matrices?

Comment: I got two favorites: SVD and Schur decomposition!

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz Can you post the description of them?

Comment: Sure! Just gimme a second :)

Comment: "Most interesting ones" : on which creteria ? Is it Usefulness ? There are hundreds of them... Is it Aesthetics ? It depends of one's sense of (mathematical) beauty...

Comment: Any which you would like to choose @Jean Marie

Answer (score 2):

The **Schur decomposition** is defined for **any square matrix** as follows:

> For any $n\times n$ matrix $A$, there exist (non necessarily unique) unitary $Q_{n\times n}$ and upper-triangular $U_{n\times n}$ such that:$$A=QUQ^H$$where $^H$ denotes the Hermitian operator (conjugate-transpose operator) and a unitary matrix is any square matrix $Q$ with the property $QQ^H=I$.

Also the **SVD** is a very important and beautiful matrix decomposition (probably the best ever!) defined for **any arbitrary matrix** as follows:

> The **Singular Value Decomposition** of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ is any triple $(U_{m\times m},D_{m\times n},V_{n\times n})$ such that $$A=UDV^H$$where $U,V$ are unitary and $D$ is diagonal as the non-diagonal entries (i.e. entries $d_{ij}$ with $i\ne j$) are all zero.

Such a decomposition exists for any matrix.

The existence of SVD for a matrix $A$ is followed a very interesting background. As any matrix $A$ can be interpreted as a linear operator from $\Bbb R^n$ onto $\Bbb R^m$, one can split the $A$-operation of a vector as below:

**Operation 1 :** a vector is first rotated in $\Bbb R^n$ by multiplying in $V$ ($V$-operation).

**Operation 2 :** the outcome vector is then multiplied in $D$ which can be interpreted as a scale and transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$ ($D$-operation).

**Operation 3 :** the final vector is once more rotated in $\Bbb R^m$ to yield the result.

SVD enjoys a widespread use in mathematical frameworks. For more information about these two and more useful  decompositions (such as Cholesky decomposition for a symmetric non-negative definite matrix), I suggest you the following links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition